# testing detail actions in viewsets

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I wrote a `Viewset` with a set authentication, permissions and serializers, and would like now to unit test it.
The problem is that when executing `UserViewSet.as_view(actions={'get': 'retrieve'})` from my test, the viewset dispatch method doesn't set `self.detail = True`.

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsFirebaseVerified, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly)
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        '''
        if a user queries his own details, or signs up, return his private info
        '''
        # BUG: self.detail is undefined
        if (self.detail and self.request.user.pk == self.kwargs.get('pk'))\
                or self.action == 'create':
            return PrivateUserSerializer
        return UserSerializer
```

Related test:

```py
def generate_fake_user_data(pk, name):
    return {
        'pk': pk,
        'email': '{}@example.com'.format(name.lower()),
        'password': 'password{}'.format(name),
    }


class UserViewSetTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.users = MockSet(
            User(**generate_fake_user_data(1, 'A')),
            User(**generate_fake_user_data(2, 'B')),
            model=User,
        )
        cls.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        UserViewSet.queryset = cls.users

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        UserViewSet.queryset = User.objects.all

    def test_authed_user_retrieves_himself(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/api/users/1/')
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.users.first())
        retrieve_view = UserViewSet.as_view(actions={'get': 'retrieve'})
        response = retrieve_view(request, pk=1)

        # BUG: response.data has been returned by UserSerializer
        # hence assert fails with email not found
        self.assertDictContainsSubset({
            'pk': 1,
            'full_name': 'John A',
            'email': 'a@example.com',
        }, response.data)
        self.assertFalse('password' in response.data)
```

What would be the proper way to call my view from my test with `self.detail` being set to `True` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, looks like I just needed to give this parameter to `as_view`

```
retrieve_view = UserViewSet.as_view(actions={'get': 'retrieve'},
                                            detail=True)
```